# Symfony - Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Loader'

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to deploy a symfony project to production but I get the following exception

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Loader' with message 'The "/home/technqoc/public_html\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle/Resources/views" directory does not exist.' in /home/technqoc/public_html/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php:93

I suspect it's because of the way the server is trying to access the directory. How can I change the backslash to forward slash in the directory path?

Comment: Can you actually navigate to a folder called `/home/technqoc/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/views`? If not, did you remember to install all the vendor dependancies on your production server (`$ php composer.php install`)?

Comment: I can navigate to it but, if you notice, the directory in my question uses forward slashes until "public_html" then it uses backslashes. "/home/technqoc/public_html" is my root directory in the production server. I have copied my files into this root directory. so it seems the server can't find "\vendor" how can I change things so that the server looks for "/vendor" instead?

Answer (score 5):

Simply clear any file and folder in cache directory.

Answer (score 4):

As @HPierce pointed out, I think you have to run "composer install" to rebuild the autoloader according to your local environment, or it will try to use the folder structure of another server.

Comment: Hi, thanks everyone for your inputs. The solution you guys are suggesting is probably the right way to solve the issue however, I have found a temporary workaround: I  used  $path =  str_replace("\\","/",$path); to replace the backslash and it seems to be working now.

Comment: @CodeSave, That's not a solution, that's a workaround. You may accept Francesco's answer as your cache-related issue should be fixed by composer.

Comment: This worked for me. For dummies on a shared hosting platform (like me), here's what you do:

1) You connect with SSH (use Putty or the like)
2) You navigate to the folder that *contains* the vendor folder and the composer.lock / composer.json (cd foo/bar/etc...)
3) You type "composer install" and hit enter
4) Voila!